# Delphi SDI application - Not handling cascade/tile horizontal & tile vertically?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-2009, windows-messages

My application doesn't seem to receive or handle the same windows messages for the Cascade, Tile Horizontal/Tile Vertical on specific windows versions.

> Windows XP x32 - Not working
> Windows XP x64     - Not tested
> Windows Vista x32  - Not working
> Windows Vista x64  - **Works fine??**
> Windows 7 x32      - Not tested
> Windows 7 x64      - Not working

Anyone any idea's as to why this may be the case? Is there anything specific to Vista x64 that isn't with the others, I wouldn't have thought so myself!

**Update**

More specifically I am referring to when I have one or more instances of my application open and I hold Ctrl and select these from the task bar and then try to Cascade/Tile.

Older versions of our application prior to upgrading to Delphi 2009 seem to work as expected. Differences from this is we are now using the DevExpress ribbon components. Even more frustratingly is we have another version of the application which is in Delphi 2009 and using the ribbons and that works fine!

Comment: How do you "trap" theses messages ? Maybe it could help

Comment: I don't trap them, I thought it was the OS that handled this?

Comment: I never even knew you could do that! For what it's worth, I just tried it with a Delphi 2006 app under WinXP-32 and you're right. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Mike, yes you can trap multiple windows messages (we actually do this on numerous occassions). However, we don't trap anything specific to this area.

Comment: @James, I meant I didn't know you could multi-select apps from the task bar and tile them. And I thought I knew everything :-} Just tried running Winspector - I can see correct WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING & WM_WINDOWPOCHANGED messages going to the queues but the app instances don't move.

Comment: What's the value of `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar`? Does it differ between the version that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: @Mike apologies! Mistunderstood what you were referring to. There are WM_MDICASCADE, WM_MDITILE messages that I would image are posted when you select those options so I wonder if I just need to trap these and do the work manually. @mghie the MainFormOnTaskbar is set to true on both versions and ShowMainForm is set to false (as we have a hidden main form).

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about Delphi's TForm.Cascade and TForm.Tile methods, from the documentation (Delphi 7, as it was handy):

```
Use Cascade to arrange MDI child forms so they overlap.

Cascade works only if the form is an MDI parent form (that is, if the form’s 
FormStyle property is fsMDIForm).
```

As you can see, they're only designed for MDI child forms; they have no effect on non-MDI child forms. That might explain why they're not working on three of the four OS's you've tested on. (I'd suspect the Vista x64 working is a fluke of some kind.)

EDIT: Based on the comment, the problem isn't related to TForm.Cascade/Tile.

I think Craig Young is on the right track, though. Have you tried adding

```
Application.ShowMainFormOnTaskbar := True;
```

to the .DPR file? I think the issue may be that, on projects started in earlier versions of Delphi and then updated to newer versions, the flag isn't set and the Application's window is what's put on the taskbar. Changing it to the main form instead may fix the issue.

Comment: I am referring to when you right click on the application when its on the task bar and selecting those options from the menu. I would have through regardless of what type of application it was it would work.

Comment: Ah, OK. The phrasing read to me like TForm.Cascade. See updated answer.

Comment: I have mentioned in the comments on the main question this has already been done. I don't think this is where the issue lies. I noticed we do trap the WM_MOVING message however it doesn't seem to get called when the Cascade/Tile options are selected.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Delphi app has two 'main' handles. One is for the main form, and the other for the TApplication instance.

Personally I don't use the functionality to tile or cascade applications on the desktop (I prefer to run things maximised). Consequently, I've never bothered to dig around with that behaviour. But I can give some pointers:

- Most likely the TApplication.WndProc method is receiving the message, but it doesn't help trying to resize that.
- I suggest you intercept the relevant messages and simply pass them on to the main form's handle.

  - The TApplication.OnMessage event is the simplest, and should suffice.
  - If not, you could try using TApplication.HookMainWindow();